# Secure method beside phpMyAdmin for remote mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, authentication

Recently, one of my centos linux servers was hacked and the cause of due to phpMyAdmin. It was said due to this problem PhpMyAdmin vulnerability CVE-2011-2505 (http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2011-2505). What is the best way to login securely into my mysql db? Any idea please.

Comment: You can connect with MySQL Workbench (via SSH tunnel).

Comment: @ypercube but then again I must open port 3306 which will become another threat to me thereafter right?

Comment: No, you only open ssh port (all other communication passes through that, that's why it's called "tunneling").

Comment: @ypercube ok first I must install the mysql workbench on that particular pc right? Then how to connect cause I saw the website show is port 3306 can you explain further on this?

Comment: You actually don't even need Workbench. Here's a quick intoduction: [MySQL ssh tunnel](http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/mysql_ssh_howto.html) With this, (while the  tunnel is working) all applications in your local machine will think that there's a MySQL server, locally at 3307. So, you can connect with either Command Line Interface or Workbench or whatever.

Comment: I usually do this when I need to connect to a remote server (where there are no vpn or other security measures). For a short-term solution, it's ok.

Comment: @ypercube ok so what I understand now is that first add user from the gateway server then connect via ssh to the gateway server.In the example the port 3007 is open on the gateway or using the standard 22 will do the work? But if I need some gui then what is the best method as sometimes it is very helpful with gui to write the scripts and testing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a VPN connection to connect to the network which is hosting the database server.

A database server should never be directly accessible from the public Internet.  If it is directly accessible it will be broken in to. It's just a mater of time.

Comment: @denny what should I do now? How do you advice me to do it? Setup vpn is it? So internally from server can I call it ?

Comment: When you setup a VPN server at the data center you then VPN into the network via that VPN server (some routers can do this as well).  At that point you are on the Data Center network and can log into the MySQL server.  I'm not a fan of pushing my book on here, but it's called Securing SQL Server (http://securingsqlserver.com/) while it's aimed at Microsoft SQL Server a lot of the concepts apply to app database platforms, especially the 1st chapter on designing your network with security in mind.

Comment: @denny the problem I am hosting all my server in data center. So one server is web server and the other db server. So are you saying first log into the webserver and then using that to login into my db server?

Comment: You should setup a separate website on the web server for running admin type apps like PhpMyAdmin and make that website so that it's not accessible from the Public Internet.  This way people can't find and access your admin functions via the public website.  Having everything on a single site may be convenient, but it it's convenient it probably isn't secure.

Comment: @denny, Say I got server A(I put now the phpMyAdmin here) then it with locally link to Server B which is my db am I right here? Is this how it suppose to be but if the compromise my server A phpMyAdmin also going to be a problem then right? When you said separate means how you suggest to be done? Thank you.

Comment: @newbie: It means that all others (the public Internet) will only see web-server C. You will have access to server A and from there, as mrdenny advised, through phpmyadmin to B. Of course, if (and only if) your vpn (which allows you to connect from outside to A) and server A are compromised, you'll be in the situation you are now.

Comment: @yercube the problem I want to try to eliminate the situation I am in so what is the best mechanism based on your past experiences. Any good advice to take on?