# User has no password set

Tags: mysql, security

I see these when running [MySQLTuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl):

```
-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[!!] User '@debian' has no password set.
[!!] User '@localhost' has no password set.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- Is it a security hole?
- How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is definite a security hole. That's because mysql was installed that way.

To remove those entries, please run these lines

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='' or password='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Here are three(3) past posts I wrote on how and why to do such cleanup of `mysql.user` and `mysql.db`

- [Secure method beside phpMyAdmin for remote mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17076/secure-method-beside-phpmyadmin-for-remote-mysql/17110#17110)
- [MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897)
- [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db)

Comment: Great answer, just a typo `FLUSH PRIVILEGES:` should be `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` with semicolon. I copy-pasted and got an error, so tried to edit the answer but I was not allowed as it is not a 6+ chars edit...