# mysqladmin user account not secure?

Tags: mysql, authentication, mysqladmin

I still playing with my own DB trying to learn and saw this:

[image]

1. I could change the root password without any problem at all... If I'm in the server I can create an algorithm to start testing password and and someday I will find it, I mean:

   `Web-Services-iMac-2:~ jbolivar$ mysqladmin -utest1 -p**SOME_THING_HERE** password test1`.
2. is it ok to change password using this???:

   update table mysql.user set password=**PASSWORD**('test')  where user='test1';

beside that if I create a dictionary table (a table with all possible words) and apply **PASSWORD**("word") I can make a join and find the value of any pass, right?.
Can you give me your opinion about my analysis?

Comment: I believe what you're referring to is commonly known as a: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table - This is why we like to force users to use complex passwords with MiXeD CaSe alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you continue playing with mysqladmin, you need to make sure your installation is not intentionally giving away access.

For starters, can you login to mysql like this?

```
# mysql <hit enter>
```

If you can get just like that, run this command:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

- [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL
- [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

If CURRENT_USER() return a user and host where the user is blank, then you were allowed in as an anonymous user. At that point, you can remove anonymou users with this:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now, locate all users with no password with this:

```
SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user;
```

If any users have no password, you can issue new passwords for user using mysqladmin or you could just assign them as follows:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('whateverpassword') WHERE user='...' AND host='...';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now, check for remote users

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE host='%';
```

If you see any, run this:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE host='%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Make sure when all is said and done that at least root@localhost and/or root@127.0.0.1 exist and have a password

```
SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root';
```

I could probably go on. Here are other posts I have about stuff like this:

- [Cannot drop anonymous user from mysql.user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/cannot-drop-anonymous-user-from-mysql-user/4615#4615)
- [MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897)
- [Secure method beside phpMyAdmin for remote mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17076/secure-method-beside-phpmyadmin-for-remote-mysql/17110#17110)
- [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db)