# Mysql user accesable with out password from the host machine but not from the remote machine

Tags: mysql

I have setup mysql and created a user 'test' and have given a password for it.

Strange thing I observed is, for test user I am able to access with out password from the machine I have installed mysql but when I try to access remotely then I need to give a password.

Why is this behaviour? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is the way MySQL authenticates and current users installed.

When you run this command

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

you quickly learn that [**USER()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) tells you how mysqld sees you trying to login and [**CURRENT_USER()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) tells you how mysqld allowed you to login. I discussed this 3 years ago in [Why does OS login not exist in the user table, but I can still login to MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17420/why-does-os-login-not-exist-in-the-user-table-but-i-can-still-login-to-mysql/17423#17423)

My guess is that whatever [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) is in mysql.user has no password.

You can run `SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user),QUOTE(host)) userhost,password FROM mysql.user;` to see your users. You might note that password is blank.

To solve your issue, you must create a remote username and password.

Comment: How do I create remote user and password? Basically it has to work only with password both in local and remote machine. That is my target.

Comment: Can you login locally as `root@localhost` ???

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ... TO user@localhost ...
and
GRANT ... TO user@'%' ...
```

are independent of each other.

Also, if the hostname is `my.site.com` or `%.site.com` or `11.22.33.44` or `11.22.33.%`, the rules get more complicated.  In particular some of these could refer to the same client, so it gets tricky as to which `GRANT` is in effect.