# Limiting database security

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008

A number of texts signify that the most important aspects offered by a DBMS are availability, integrity and secrecy. As part of a homework assignment I have been tasked with mentioning attacks which would affect each aspect.  This is what I have come up with - are they any good?

- Availability - DDOS attack Integrity
- Secrecy - SQL Injection attack
- Integrity - Use of trojans to gain access to objects with higher security roles

Answer (score 1):

SQL Injection would be straightforward if [scripting code was not properly sanitizing its inputs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Here is a good post on SQL Injection Prevention via Stored Procedures : [Do stored procedures prevent SQL injection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127/do-stored-procedures-prevent-sql-injection)

Interestingly, even in the book [MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127), Chapter 33 is all about using Stored Procedures and Triggers for Administration. In it are three bulletpoints on Page 470:

> For the tables in question, disallow direct access to by ordinary
>   users for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. (You can do this be
>   granting the appropriate privileges to administrative users only.)
>
> Implement a procedural interface for modifying each table. That is,
>   using an administrative account that has access to the table, write
>   stored procedure that have DEFINER security and that perform the
>   required modifications to the table, giving appropriate data values as
>   parameters. Grant the EXECUTE privilege for these routines to the
>   appropriate users.
>
> Require users to perform table modifications by calling the stored
>   procedures and passing column values for the rows to be modified as
>   parameters. Each procedure examines its arguments and verifies that
>   they satisfy whatever constraints are deemed necessary. If the
>   arguments are suitable, the procedure performs the requested
>   modification. If they are not, the procedure aborts the operation.

In another mysql aspect, you have to secure user authentication. The most overlooked aspect is looking for the mysql schema tables. I wrote about this before in terms of how user authentication works and how to clean it up at install time and later afterwards:

- [What is the mysql.db table used for?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13327/what-is-the-mysql-db-table-used-for/13350#13350)
- [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db)
- [Is this a normal set of MySQL privileges?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5620/is-this-a-normal-set-of-mysql-privileges/5624#5624)
- [Secure method beside phpMyAdmin for remote mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17076/secure-method-beside-phpmyadmin-for-remote-mysql/17110#17110)